# C# syntax for new object with if statement for id and string

Tags: c#, syntax

I have a model class like this:

```
 public class TypeMinimal : BaseMinimal {

    private string _name = "";

    public TypeMinimal(int? id, string name = "")
        : base(id, "types", API.Enum.Types) {
        _name = name;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
}
```

And I am trying to populate a property based on whether the type is 1 or 2.  Eg

```
 type = new TypeMinimal(item.Type == 1 ? 1 : 2)
```

I would like to add the type name as well as the type id to the property but I am not sure of the syntax.  This is what I have tried but it is not correct:

```
  type = new TypeMinimal(item.Type == 1 ? 1, "volunteer" : 2, "staff"),
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you move this logic into constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
type = item.Type == 1 ? new TypeMinimal(1, "volunteer") : new TypeMinimal(2, "staff");
```